# Обновление состояния ярлыка (изменение иконки)

Tags: windows

Цель:
Хочу перенести корзину на панель задач.
Открываю корзину и перетаскиваю иконку на рабочий стол.
На рабочем столе появился ярлык корзины.

Проблема:
создаю папку и файл, удаляю, тут же значок корзины меняется.
значок ярлыка остается прежним, но обновляется если перезагрузить explorer.exe
(при изменении значка любой другой папки с помощью Folder Painter, иконка ярлыка тоже меняется)

Вопросы:
Можно ли как-то прописать чтобы ярлык тоже обновлялся? Или добавить к команде 'обновить'?
Можно ли добавить к ярлыку правой кнопкой команду 'Очистить корзину'?
(например дублировав .lnk на .lnkk и прописать новую команду только для таких ярлыков)

Пробовал:
Хотел сделать по аналогии с God Mode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
Корзина.{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Ярлык создался, без иконки ярлыка, но он тоже не обновляется.

Comment: смотрю в сторону vbs скриптов, подскажите какие еще варианты есть кроме CreateObject и CreateShortcut? Например CreateGUID???

Answer (score 0):

корзина это системная папка. чтобы она отображалась на рабочем столе, не надо создавать ярлык. В случае с win10 надо отрыть ***Персоанализация -> Темы***. Справа выбрать ***Параметры значков рабочего стола***, и в открывшемся диалоговом окне установить галку у корзины.

тогда у вас и контекстное меню адекватное будет и с обновлением иконки не будет проблем.

Comment: Ответ отклонен! Задача не просто создать ярлык, а впихнуть его в панель задач!

Comment: в целом можно как вы указали создать папку переименовав ее с GUID корзины, добавить новую панель на  таскбар с этой папкой (родительской). но иконка корзины все равно не обновляется при заполненности. А чтобы на корзине было нужное контекстное меню надо работать не с ярлыком. об этом речь шла в моем ответе.

Comment: есть идеи как менять ярлык?

Answer (score 0):

Резюме:
Перетащил иконку напрямую из корзины на панель задач.
При нажатии правой кнопкой мыши есть пункт 'Очистить корзину'.
При очищении иконка меняется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще:
Добавил в контекстное меню 2 параметра
1) Перезапустить проводник Windows
2) Перестроить кэш значков Windows
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для справки:
Думаю можно будет добавить код команды 2) в команду 'Обновить' через &.
И получим обновление кэша значков при команде обновить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать автоматизировать вот этот скрипт.(vbs)

---

```js
'Скрипт правильно обновляет Рабочий стол, очищая (обновляя) кэш иконок командами в 8-ой и 9-ой строках.
'Побочным действием такой очистки кэша и обновления оболочки является создание файлов-отчётов.
'Команды, начинающиеся с 14-ой строки, отвечают за удаление этих логов после паузы в 1 секунду (10-я строка).
'13-я строка указывает сценарию переменную среду %userprofile%, которую Microsoft ® WBSH по умолчанию не понимает.
'Автор скрипта: Аванесян Х.С.

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "ie4uinit.exe -show"
oShell.run "ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache"
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
If objFSO.FileExists(USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-ClearIconCache.log") Then
objFSO.DeleteFile USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-ClearIconCache.log"
End If
If objFSO.FileExists(USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-show.log") Then
objFSO.DeleteFile USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-show.log"
End If
If objFSO.FileExists(USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\brndlog.txt") Then
objFSO.DeleteFile USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\brndlog.txt"
End If
If objFSO.FileExists(USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-UserConfig.log") Then
objFSO.DeleteFile USERPROFILE &"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ie4uinit-UserConfig.log"
End If
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Может оставить как есть и принять за доп ответ?

Comment: Покажите путь в реестре к комманде 'Обновить', чет найти не могу.

Comment: Есть ли простые способы использовать на данном форуме табуляцию и переход на новую строку кроме HTML кода br, pre и закидывания в виде кода?